# How could I set a div's position based on the screen using Jquery scrollto

Tags: jquery, css, scrollto, nav

I am using Jquery's Scrollto plugin to scroll up and down based on a menu but I would like the menu to stay with the scroller.  So if I had a page that was 4000px high and someone clicks the link that takes them down to the 2000px point the menu would slide down there too.  Not sure if this is a css or jquery issue.  Any help is very appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use position:fixed in your css.  Here is an example in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/E8Hyw/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time picturing what you're trying to do, so this may be off by quite a bit:

You could try putting the menu outside of the scrolling area and floating its div over the portion that is scrolling.  Your content might not be best suited to that though.

Depending on what you're trying to do, that might be a little more semantically correct as well. The menu isn't part of the content itself but is rather the navigation for the content.

Posting a partial chunk of html/js and/or a link or image that mocks up what you're trying to do would help a bit.

Comment: Jim. I am trying to think through what your talking about... For instance: http://line25.com/tutorials/designing-an-infographic-with-html-css-and-jquery  shows the use of scrollto to jump down a page.  But what if there was a nav available at all times.  Even something as simple as a simple UL.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think most of the scrollTo's I've seen are using it as a smaller view pane kind of deal. I think you've really just got the standard floating div question then. See @jhanifen's sample and/or google floating div. I can post more of a sample if you need.